# Assigning to the real or imaginary part of a complex number in C

Tags: c, complex-numbers

I need to work on complex to extract imaginary roots of polynomial using Newton's method.

I'm getting an error, so I broke the code down to simple problem to see what's wrong. When I try to compile it it returns an error:

> warning: target of assignment not really an lvalue; this will be a hard error in the future

Also I would like to know if there is anyway I can display the whole complex number without going with `creal` and `cimag`.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<complex.h>

int main()
{
  double complex z1 = 2 + 3*I;
  creal(z1) = 5;
  cimag(z1) = 10;
  printf("%.2f +%.2f *i \n", creal(z1), cimag(z1));
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is a duplicate. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19175776/a-function-returning-reference-to-real-or-imag-values-of-a-complex-number-in-c/19176414#19176414

Answer (score 2):

The problem is these lines:

```
creal(z1) = 5;
cimag(z1) = 10;
```

creal and cimag return doubles.  You cannot assign to a functions return value.  You can assign the return value of a function to another variable like  `double real = creal(z1)`.

Comment: So how do I assign values to z?? I need z to start from the top left corner and goes to the bottom right in 2x2 square. I will use a nested loop for that. so the first value of z would be z = -2 + 2i and loop through the entire graph until it gets to z = 2 - 2i.. This way I would test every single point in that square.. So how could I assign different values to z.. I know how to do it if it were real but with z it doesn't work as it returns an error

Comment: Probably: `z1 = CMPLX(5, 10);`  I'm clear whether there are supported alternatives.  If you want to do it in two steps, then: `z1 = CMPLX(5, cimag(z1)); z1 = CMPLX(creal(z1), 10);`.