# a function returning reference to real or imag values of a complex number in C++11

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11, complex-numbers

I'm looking for a function that returns a reference to real or imag values of  a complex number in C++11. In C++03 I could say:

`complex<double> C; cin >> C.real();`

But in C++11 that gives me a compile error since the C.real() returns a value not a reference.

I found out that I can write this:

`double t;   cin >> t;   C.real(t);`

but it isn't straightforward and for example if I want to multiply the real part of c by 2 and ad it by 1 I should say:

`C.real(2*C.real() + 1);`

That is not clean.

Is there any other [clean] way to do that?

Comment: While it might not be "clean" to you, it might be for someone else. It's all a question of style and personal preference.

Comment: I wouldn't say assigning a value into a returned reference from a function is a clean technique.

Comment: `C.real() = 2*C.real() + 1;` is not clean either, as per **my** taste.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: Disagree, "clean-ness" is not a personal but a team issue. We have to agree on some shared definition - even if not shared by all.

Comment: @Nawaz: I agree - but only because complex could be immutable without repercussions (with todays optimizers and on most of todays platforms).

Comment: IMO, if you want to use non-const reference, it might mean that you actually need a struct, not class. Either that or you should simply make internal variable public.

Comment: In my opinion, they should have left out the setters as well.

Comment: @Troy You would never use the `[]` operator of a `std::vector` or `std::map` I presume :) http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at

Comment: Does that operation even make mathematical sense? Adding 1 to the real part does, that's just adding `(1 + 0*i)`. But that "multiplication"?

Comment: @MSalters: mathematically speaking, that op is `C + (C + conj(C))/2 + 1`. So it's a little unusual but not nonsensical. You could argue that mutating operations *never* make mathematical sense, mathematics is a pure functional language, but once you allow that, mutating just the real part of `C` might make sense :-)

Comment: @SteveJessop: Fair point.In C++ that would be `C += (C + C.conj())/2 + 1;` and you wouldn't need access to the real component.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sorry to be negative, but your question starts from a wrong premise. Concerning `std::complex` the 2011 standard is backward compatible. Code of the form

```
complex<double> C; cin >> C.real();
```

was **never valid C++**. The 2003 standard only gives the member function

```
T std::complext<T>::real() const;
```

but not

```
const T& std::complext<T>::real() const;  // non-standard
T& std::complext<T>::real();              // non-standard
```

even though some implementations (such as that shipped with gcc 4.3) may have implemented these two instead.

Now, **to answer your question**. Clearly, the cleanest way is to follow the intention of the standard. The 2011 standard adds the following setters

```
void std::complex<T>::real(T);
void std::complex<T>::imag(T);
```

so you can now simply use those to set the real or imaginary parts separately.

However, those cannot be used in a function taking `T&`, such as `operator>>`. For that you must do some nasty tricks like

```
template<typename T>
inline T& get_real(std::complex<T>&z) { return reinterpret_cast<T(&)[2]>(z)[0]; }

template<typename T>
inline T& get_imag(std::complex<T>&z) { return reinterpret_cast<T(&)[2]>(z)[1]; }

std::complex<double> z;
cin >> get_real(z) >> get_imag(z);
```

Actually, as pointed out in a comment by bames53, the standard guarantees `std::complex` to be laid out such that this always works.

Comment: From cppreference: `void real( T value ); (2) ... 2) Sets the real part to value.` From [`n3337`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf), page 880: `void real(T val);
Eﬀects: Assigns val to the real component.`

Comment: the C++11 standard has very detailed specification on the layout of `std::complex<T>`. It cannot store its members in reverse order or have any padding: see 26.4[complex.numbers]/4

Comment: @Walter C++11 does guarantee the layout of `std::complex`. For example it says given `std::complex<T> z;`, `reinterpret_cast<T(&)[2]>(z)[0]` will access the real component and `reinterpret_cast<T(&)[2]>(z)[1]` will access the imaginary component.

Comment: @bames53, correct, the details are here https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex and scroll down. This is critical to use C++ with C and the like numerical libraries. Since they took the work to specify all this, they standard should have allowed `real(c)` and `imag(c)` to return references and call it a day.

Answer (score 5):

If you really want to separate input for real and imaginary parts of a complex, you could try IO manipulators approach.

```
#include <complex>
#include <iosfwd>

class proxy_complex {
    explicit proxy_complex(std::istream& strm, bool f)
        : strm_(&strm), flag(f) { }
    proxy_complex(const proxy_complex&) = default;

    std::istream* strm_;
    bool flag;           // flag to check whether we're writing real or imag

public:
    template<typename T>
    std::istream& operator>>(std::complex<T>& c)
    {
        T n;
        if (*strm_ >> n)
            flag ? c.real(n) : c.imag(n);
        return *strm_;
    }

    friend proxy_complex operator>>(std::istream& is, proxy_complex(*func)(std::istream&))
    {
        return func(is);
    }
    friend proxy_complex real(std::istream&);
    friend proxy_complex imag(std::istream&);
};

inline proxy_complex real(std::istream& is)
{
    return proxy_complex(is, true);
}

inline proxy_complex imag(std::istream& is)
{
    return proxy_complex(is, false);
}
```

You can put the above code in a header file of its own (if you do that, it might be a good idea to wrap it in a namespace).

Usage:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "my_header.h"

int main()
{
    std::complex<double> c;
    std::cin >> real >> c >> imag >> c;
    if (std::cin) std::cout << c;
}
```

Hope I guessed your definition of "clean" correctly :)

Answer (score 4):

C++11 now allows

```
double& re(std::complex<double>& c)
{
    return reinterpret_cast<double (&)[2]>(c)[0];
}

double& im(std::complex<double>& c)
{
    return reinterpret_cast<double (&)[2]>(c)[1];
}

const double& re(const std::complex<double>& c)
{
    return reinterpret_cast<const double (&)[2]>(c)[0];
}

const double& im(const std::complex<double>& c)
{
    return reinterpret_cast<const double (&)[2]>(c)[1];
}
```

Usage:

```
std::complex<double> a;
std::cin >> re(a);
```

Relevant quote §26.4:

> Moreover, if a is an expression of type `cv std::complex<T>*` and the expression `a[i]` is well-defined for an integer expression `i` , then:
>    — `reinterpret_cast<cv T*>(a)[2*i]` shall designate the real part of `a[i]`, and 
>   — `reinterpret_cast<cv T*>(a)[2*i+1]` shall designate the imaginary part of `a[i]` .

Answer (score 2):

If you want to manipulate real parts you can just use double or floats directly.
If you want to manipulate imaginary parts you can have a unique complex number `std::complex<double> I(0,1)` and multiply it by the value you want.

For instance, instead of writing: `C.real(2*C.real() + 1);` you can write: `C += C.real() + 1;`

Then you can mix doubles with complexs in your mathematical expressions and the compiler will use the correct conversions. See an example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <complex>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    // Let the user enter a Real number
    double c;
    std::cin >> c;

    // Explicitly convert to a complex
    std::complex<double> C = 2*c + 1;
    std::cout << C << std::endl;

    // Creates a pure imaginary complex number I
    std::complex<double> I(0,1);

    // Mix together complex and real numbers in the
    // same expression
    C = C + c*I;
    std::cout << C << std::endl;


    // Setup a specific value and compare how to achieve
    // C.real = 2*C.real + 1
    C = 1. + 2.*I;
    C.real(2*C.real()+1);
    std::complex<double> D = 1. + 2.*I;
    D += D.real() + 1;
    std::cout << "C=" << C << "\tD=" << D << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The output:

```
$ ./main.exe
1
(3,0)
(3,1)
C=(3,2) D=(3,2)

$ ./main.exe
2
(5,0)
(5,2)
C=(3,2) D=(3,2)
```

If you are afraid of the lost of efficiency of this method compared to affecting directly through a reference you can look at the generated assembly code. On my computer with `g++` and `-O3` everything is inlined.

Answer (score 1):

Not that I know of.

You could construct a helper if that's important to you:

```
class ModifyReal
{
   double d;
   complex<double> & c;
public:
   ModifyReal(complex<double> & c_) : c(c_), d(numeric_limits<double>::quiet_NaN()) 
   {}
   operator double &() { return d; }
   ~ModifyReal() { c.real(d); }
};


cin >> ModifyReal(C);
```

I would not exactly *recommend* to use this, however, unless you have a very compelling reason to. ("I do not like it" is not convincing enough.)

I do think having many different classes like this in your code can hamper readability, but if you use it in a few dedicated instances you should be fine. Error handling can become subtley difficult (e.g. since cin doesn't throw on invalid input, C gets assigned nan,  rather than being unmodified.)

---

What does "clean" mean? No, don't tell me - think about it.

Comment: Well, if you stop calling the helper RealRef and call it ModifyReal, I would call your code clean and elegant. +1 from me goes anyway, the solution is compliant and solved the problem.

Comment: @Suma: Renamed the class, maybe it make client code a bit more obvious indeed.I, too, think it's a good solution - unless it is overused.

Answer (score -2):

Inspired by Steve Jessop, it's just `C += (C + C.conj())/2 + 1;`.

Remember that in complex math, you cannot really treat the real and imaginary parts as fully independent components. That's just about as sane than treating their phase and magnitude as fully independent components. Addition of complex numbers is done independently on real and imaginary parts, but multiplication is done independently on the phase and magnitude parts.

Your example is not complex multiplication, so it makes sense that `std::complex` doesn't support that kind of multiplication.

Comment: The operation of multiplying only the real or imaginary part is a certain kind of homography. And it certainly has a mathematical sense. The fact it is not supported in C++ is because the language lacks a standard matrix class. And I don't say it's bad, just that matrix is not standard.